# SQL Select MAX value only when condition not match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select max prices only when certain condition on the table are met. The table consist of this column

```
| id | product_item_code | distribution_channel | sap_no_shipto | valuation_type | price |
|----|-------------------|----------------------|---------------|----------------|-------|
| 1  | A                 | A                    | A             | NULL           | 200   |
| 2  | A                 | A                    | A             | B              | 2000  |
| 3  | A                 | A                    | A             | C              | 3000  |
```

I want to apply this logic

1. If the `valuation_type` are NULL use the `price` from that row
2. If the `valuation_type` are not null, use the highest price

Table have unique constrain combination

```
product_item_code | distribution_channel | sap_no_shipto | valuation_type
```

For now, I code it like this, but it doesn't satisfy the first condition.

Below are the subquery. Is there any way to apply the logic? Because this query only select the MAX price if there are `null` on valuation type, it will ignore it.

```sql
            SELECT MAX(psp.price)
            FROM product_special_prices psp
            WHERE
              psp.product_item_code = p.item_code AND
              psp.distribution_channel = st.distribution_channel AND
              psp.sap_no_shipto = st.sap_no_shipto
            GROUP BY (
              psp.product_item_code,
              psp.distribution_channel,
              psp.sap_no_shipto
            )
```

Comment: That's not a valid SQL query, for example p.item_code would not exists.

Comment: So, you want to get the MAX if no record has a NULL value? And you want to get the price of the NULL record if exists instead of the MAX? What if two records have NULL?

Comment: Yup this is a subquery sorry @FrankHeikens.

Comment: Yes @S-Man. The table have unique constrain, so the value cannot be null twice. I'll update the example sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by price and take the highest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_item_code, distribution_channel, sap_no_shipto)
       price
FROM product_special_prices
ORDER BY product_item_code, distribution_channel, sap_no_shipto,
         valuation_type IS NOT NULL, price DESC;
```

This will sort the rows with `valuation_type` of value NULL first, because `FALSE < TRUE`. `DISTINCT ON` will return the first row for each group.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, you could use the `coalesce` and filtered max function as the following:

```
select product_item_code, distribution_channel, sap_no_shipto,
       coalesce(max(price) filter (where valuation_type is null),
                max(price) filter (where valuation_type is not null)) mx
from product_special_prices
group by product_item_code, distribution_channel, sap_no_shipto
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/waTo06Ko)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

SELECT *
,NewColumn = CASE WHEN valuation_type  IS NOT NULL THEN tb.price ELSE tb2.PriceMax END
FROM table tb

OUTER APPLY (
SELECT PriceMax =  MAX(price) FROM table
) tb2